# Nginx Not Redirecting to Local Instances

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, load-balancing

When I access `localhost:8080/`, it displays the nginx default page; it should redirect to my instances. I want any request to `localhost:8080/` to redirect to my instances.

My configurations:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  golang-instance:
    image: "myapi"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - nginx_net
    restart: on-failure

  golang-instance-2:
    image: "myapi"
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    networks:
      - nginx_net
    restart: on-failure

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    networks:
      - nginx_net
    restart: on-failure

networks:
  nginx_net:
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
upstream backend {
    least_conn;
    server golang-instance:5000;
    server golang-instance-2:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

When I access `localhost:8080/hello`, it should display "Hello World" because that's what my instances return. In fact, if I access `localhost:5000/hello` or `localhost:5001/hello`, both correct display "Hello World". However, what I'm getting in the browser is the nginx 404 page with the message `"404 Not Found."` The log in the container:

> 2023-09-30T18:32:28.873946632Z 172.20.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2023:18:32:28
> +0000] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"

I tried removing `least_conn`, i tried setting port 8080 in the `listen` directive, and port 5001 in `golang-instance-2` from my `nginx.conf` file, as these are the ports running on my machine. However, it didn't change the result.

I also changed the configuration of my `network` to the following:

```
networks:
  nginx_net:
    driver: bridge
```

And it didn't change anything; all these attempts didn't yield any different results.

I tried changing the `volumes` in my `docker-compose`:

```
#option-1
volumes:
  - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

#option-2
volumes:
  - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf

#option-3
volumes:
  - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/http.d/nginx.conf
```

With `option-3`, the container doesn't start; it gives an error:

> 2023/09/30 18:14:48 [emerg] 1#1: "upstream" directive is not allowed
> here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1 2023-09-30T18:14:48.131910502Z nginx:
> [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in
> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

But with option-1 and option-2, the container starts normally with the following log:

> o log  /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will
> attempt to perform configuration 2023-09-30T17:40:27.718888715Z
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in
> /docker-entrypoint.d/ 2023-09-30T17:40:27.720393590Z
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching
> /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
> 2023-09-30T17:40:27.724760049Z 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info:
> IPv6 listen already enabled 2023-09-30T17:40:27.724773299Z
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing
> /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
> 2023-09-30T17:40:27.725033174Z /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching
> /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
> 2023-09-30T17:40:27.731775465Z /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching
> /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
> 2023-09-30T17:40:27.736814424Z /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration
> complete; ready for start up 2023-09-30T17:40:27.759872299Z 2023/09/30
> 17:40:27 [warn] 1#1: conflicting server name "localhost" on
> 0.0.0.0:80, ignored 2023-09-30T17:40:27.759900590Z nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
> 2023-09-30T17:40:27.760202507Z 2023/09/30 17:40:27 [notice] 1#1: using
> the "epoll" event method 2023-09-30T17:40:27.760207549Z 2023/09/30
> 17:40:27 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.2 2023-09-30T17:40:27.760209590Z
> 2023/09/30 17:40:27 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian
> 12.2.0-14)  2023-09-30T17:40:27.760211382Z 2023/09/30 17:40:27 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.49-linuxkit
> 2023-09-30T17:40:27.760213090Z 2023/09/30 17:40:27 [notice] 1#1:
> getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
> 2023-09-30T17:40:27.761007132Z 2023/09/30 17:40:27 [notice] 1#1: start
> worker processes 2023-09-30T17:40:27.761015632Z 2023/09/30 17:40:27
> [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22 2023-09-30T17:40:27.764749424Z
> 2023/09/30 17:40:27 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
> 2023-09-30T17:40:27.764774007Z 2023/09/30 17:40:27 [notice] 1#1: start
> worker process 24 2023-09-30T17:40:27.764776340Z 2023/09/30 17:40:27
> [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25

Nevertheless, even with `option-1` and `option-2`, Nginx still doesn't redirect to the instances. I even made sure that these volumes were correctly mapped. I entered the container, navigated to the directory, and confirmed that the `nginx.conf` file was as I specified.

I'm quite stuck at the moment and not sure what else to try. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue further would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work; I needed to make the following changes to get it working:

In the `docker-compose.yml`, the change I made was in the volumes section.

```
volumes:
  - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

And the `nginx.conf` has changed completely; it now looks like this:

```
events {
}

http {
    upstream instances {
        least_conn;
        server golang-instance:5000;
        server golang-instance-2:5000;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://instances;
        }
    }
}
```